# Is there a TOC control available for Esri's Silverlight/WPF SDK?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, wpf

I've got a requirement calling for a TOC control on a Silverlight/WPF application.  Does anyone know of a TOC control (analogous to the TOCControl in ArcGIS Engine) that I can hook into Esri's Map control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out the [Legend](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Legend.html) in the Toolkit? See sample here: [Legend with templates](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/samples/start.htm#LegendWithTemplates)

Comment: Thanks Mathias - looks like a good excuse to move to 2.1.

Comment: Note also that, since the control is part of the Toolkit (http://esrisilverlight.codeplex.com), its source will be available at 2.1 final, which is coming very soon.  So if it doesn't do exactly everything you need, you still have a great place to start.

Comment: An other reason would be o check out the gestures for the mulit-touch screens. http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/help/index.html?Whats_New.htm